# Trying to split string with escaped and non-escaped delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with the form of `a b/c\/d\/e/f`. I'm trying to split the string on the non-escaped forward slashes.

I have this regex so far `(?:[^\\/])/`. However it consumes the last character preceding the `/`. So if I'm doing a replace with "#" instead of a split, the string looks like `a #c\/d\/#f`. In the case of the split, I get the strings separated the same with the last character being consumed.

I tried using a non capturing group but that doesn't seem to do the trick either. Doing this in javascript.

Comment: @anubhava ah I'll add that to the question. Doing this in javascript.

Comment: Can backslash also be escaped like `a b/c\/d\\/e/f` ?

Comment: Can't modify the source strings, really.

Comment: Try using `(?:[a-z ])(\/)(?:[a-z ])` and then selecting group 1 on your code. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178597/non-capture-group-still-showing-in-match

Comment: Not asking to modify source input, I am asking if it is possible to get input as: `a b/c\/d\\/e/f` and with expected output as `['a b', 'c\/d\\', 'e' ,'f']` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex in JS to return you all the matches before `/` ignoring all escaped cases i.e. `\/`. This regex also takes care of the cases when `\` is also escaped as `\\`.

```
/[^\\\/]*(?:\\.[^\\\/]*)*(?=\/|$)/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RnKYza/4)

```js
const regex = /[^\\\/]*(?:\\.[^\\\/]*)*(?=\/|$)/gm
const str = `\\\\\\\\\\\\/a b/c\\/d\\\\/e\\\\\\/f1/2\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/23/99`;

let m = str.match(regex).filter(Boolean)

console.log(m)
```

- `.filter(Boolean)` is used to filter out empty matches.

Comment: You say it will handle cases when ``\`` appears escaped, but [it does not work](https://regex101.com/r/RnKYza/3) for, say, ``\\\\\\/a b``.

Comment: `[^\\\/]*(?:\\.[^\\\/]*)*(?=\/|$)` can be used with `.filter(Boolean)` to get rid of empty matches